# Angularjs query does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hello friends my english is poor. i'm sorry

How to use it

```
ng-click="bak = {{maclar.macid}}"

<div><span ng-class="{class:bak == true}" ng-click="bak = {{maclar.macid}}" class="butonYap">{{bak}}{{maclar.macSonucu[0]}}</span></div>
```

Comment: What were you trying to do, and how does what you have not work?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are having trouble setting the variable `bak` when when the `ng-click` is fired.

You do not need interpolation `{{ }}` inside an `ng-click`.  Inside the quotes, angular will already interpret it as an expression:

```
ng-click="bak = maclar.macid"
```

Comment: No probs.  Hope this was what you were after.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!